# Request and sleeping time manager with tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I have list of twitter ID and I want to get all his friends and his followers to create a graph of my users. But I figured out a problem since the API rate limit is 15 requests / 15 minutes for both methods: friends_ids and followers_ids and a user may have more than 75 000 followers or friends. I did the following code:

```
for user in users:
    followers_cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, id=user.twitter_id,
                                 count=5000,
                                 wait_on_rate_limit=True,
                                 wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
    followers = []
    for follower_id in followers_cursor.items():
        followers.append(follower_id)
    friends_cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.friends_id, id=user.twitter_id,
                                 count=5000,
                                 wait_on_rate_limit=True,
                                 wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
    friends = []
    for friend_id in friends_cursor.items():
        friends.append(friend_id)
```

The problem is the sleep at the "followers_ids" endpoint will postpone my program to launch the request from the "friends_ids" even if this one still have request available.

Tweepy is quite a famous library and I guess some people already wanted to do something similar to build a graph of some users but I didn't find any methods in the library managing both "friend_ids" and "followers_id" to use the requests of both endpoint and then make them sleep together.

How can I solve this problem?